# how to get data for a gerrit

Tags: android, git, gerrit, repository

I use the following query to get the data of all the open gerrits in the project "platform/vendor/company/code",now i ONLY want to get data for a specific gerrit..lets say there is a gerrit #12345..I want to get the data for this gerrit..is there a gerrit query that can be written for this?

```
ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --current-patch-set --commit-message --files 'status:open project:platform/vendor/company/code branch:master label:Developer-Verified=1 AND label:Code-Review>=1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace the query string with the gerrit change number.  So for your example,

`ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --current-patch-set --commit-message --files '12345'`